# Promises with superagent

Tags: node.js

So the function getStuff works, but whenever there is an error in the .get method I run into a problem. See `getStuff2`.

```
const request = require('superagent');

function getStuff() {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request
      .get('http://google.com')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        console.log('getting to end cb');
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(res.body);
      })
  });

}

function getStuff2() {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request
      .get('abc')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        console.log('getting to end cb');
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(res.body);
      })
  });

}

//works
getStuff().then(function (htmlBody) {
  console.log(htmlBody);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('err');
});

//doesn't work
getStuff2().then(function (htmlBody) {
  console.log(htmlBody);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('err');
});
```

It seems like the errors from superagent are not getting handled correctly in `getStuff2` because I don't see the console log message in the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @robertklep pointed out, there is a DNS resolution problem. Here are the locally routed DNS wildcards stats.research.icann.org/dns/wildcard. If you change the code to a different dummy url the errors are caught. i.e.

```
const request = require('superagent');

function getStuff2() {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request
      .get('bing-bong-bang')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        console.log('getting to end cb');
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(res.body);
      })
  });

}

getStuff2().then(function (htmlBody) {
  console.log(htmlBody);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('err');
}
```

In this example the error is caught properly. The DNS error will eventually timeout, but it takes a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You're very vague about the exact problem you're experiencing, but it fails for me on this code:

```
if (err) reject(err);
resolve(res.body);
```

Calling `reject` doesn't cause the rest of the code to stop running, so it's causing a subsequent exception because `res` is undefined (and hence accessing `res.body` will throw a `TypeError`).

It's good practise to end the current function after you rejected a promise:

```
if (err) return reject(err);
```

Or make it an if-else:

```
if (err) {
  reject(err);
} else {
  resolve(res.body);
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness. The problem is that i don't see the `console.log('err')` message on `getStuff2`. That is why i was saying the errors are not being handled correctly.

Comment: @user3795202 that's because the `TypeError` that is being thrown.

Comment: This is not true for me. I don't see this console.log either `console.log('getting to end cb');`. So my code isn't even getting to the superagent `.end` callback. I am using node `6.3.0` and native promises (shouldn't matter).  Also to be clear, my program is just hanging.

Comment: @user3795202 that sounds like Node is stuck in making a DNS request, or that `abc` actually resolves to something and it gets stuck on making the HTTP request. Try stripping down your example code to the bare minimum (`request.get('abc').end(...)`) and see how that works.

Comment: You're right. Looks like there are some DNS rules for abc (see http://stats.research.icann.org/dns/wildcard/) . Changing the url to something else gives me the error immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
getStuff2().then(function (htmlBody) {
  console.log(htmlBody);
}, function(err) {
  throw err;
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

Reject doesn't throw an error, you're responsible for that yourself.

Comment: Doesn't matter, `reject()` should trigger a call to `.catch()`.

Comment: This has the same problem for me where it just hangs because `getStuff2()` doesn't finish.